# Reading smartphone sensor data through a remote website

Tags: javascript, android, html

Is it possible to read sensor data from smartphones when they browse a remote website? In other words, assume there is a website called www.xyz.com that requests for some sensor data like accelerometer reading when someone browses that page. Is this possible (raw values are fine)? If so, what is the easiest way to do that? Could you point me to some useful links.

Comment: I am not usre but jQuery Mobile can do it using accelerometer. http://www.jquerytutorial.in/tutor/phonegap/accelerometer.watchAcceleration

Comment: @HardikTrivedi this tutorial is for phonegap, a system that converts HTML application into an application that runs on the phone.  The API it describes is not available to a remote web site.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.  Sensors are not accessible to remote web sites because access to them could cause a privacy violation.

Comment: BTW can you provide some useful links stating that sensor data can't be accessed. I kind of thought if the browser requested permissions you could still obtain such data.